# Turn a alpha and displacement texture in a actual mesh

Tags: mesh, transparency, displacement

[image]

Hi everyone, I was wondering if there's any way for convert this texture (obviously I'm talking about the grid) that is made with alpha opacity and displacement into an actual mesh

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "made with alpha opacity and displacement", do you mean that it is not a 3D object and you want to model it?

Comment: this a blender project, what you see there for the grid it's not the mesh but the texture, the holes are made with alpha

Comment: So what do you mean by convert into a mesh? Model the object? If so, you could use a b&w image to get the shape but anyway you'll need to work on it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.